# Практика использование ООП

Tags: php

Есть рабочий код, который выводит имя пользователя и возраст, какое здесь есть преимущество у ООП?

Я вижу только очень много кода, который можно написать в функциональном стиле, в 2 раза меньше.

Это хороший код?

Вообще у меня с применением ООП беда.

```
<?php
    class Db
    {
        private $link;
        private $host = 'localhost';
        private $user = 'root';
        private $password = '';
        private $database = 'oop';
        private $table = 'users';

        //Подключается к базе:
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->link = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->password, $this->database );
        }

        //Делает запрос к базе:
        public function get($id, $field)
        {
            $query = $this->createSelect($id, $field);
            $result = $this->makeQuery($query); //будет в виде ['age'=>25]
            return $result[$field]; //а тут достанем 25
        }

        //Создает строку с запросом:
        private function createSelect($id, $field)
        {
            $table = $this->table;
            return "SELECT $field FROM $table WHERE id=$id";
        }

        //Совершает запрос к базе:
        private function makeQuery($query)
        {
            $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query);
            return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        }
    }

    $bazaDan = new Db;

    echo $bazaDan->get('1', 'name');
    echo '<br>';


    class User
    {
        private $id;
        private $db;

        public function __construct($id)
        {
            $this->id = $id;

            //Создаем объект для работы с БД:
            $this->db = new Db;
        }

        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->db->get($this->id, 'name');
        }

        public function getAge()
        {
            return $this->db->get($this->id, 'age');
        }

    }

    $user = new User('1');

    echo $user->getName();
    echo '<br>';
    echo $user->getAge();

?>
```

Comment: Это уже личное мнение и предпочтение. Я к примеру тоже предпочитаю функциональный код, а обертки использую только когда от этого действительно есть польза - в проектах, где есть разграничение, границы. В вашем примере это больше похоже на лабораторную работу по ООП т.к. в рабочем коде нет смысла оборачивать одну строку кода - только если есть наследующие классы, и эта строка действительно делает общее дело для них.

Comment: Писать ООП ради ООП - нет никакого смысла. У Вконтакте половина двига на функциях - ниче, живут ребята. Так что нужно смотреть глубже   и детальнее на то, что за проект. Хотя большинство работодателей не думают головой - им подавай ООП потому что типа "все же пишут"

Answer (score 1):

1. Код довольно сильно захламлен. В зависимости от того, каким шаблоном проектирования ты пользуешься, стоит использовать все плюсы. К примеру, вывести данные подключения БД в глобальные константы, чтобы и вне класса возможно было использовать.
2. Использовать наследования. Если у тебя уже описан класс Db, то в своем классе User, ты его можешь наследовать, как это делается в MVC.
3. Функциональный и вправду был бы проще, определенный плюс в том, что это возможность более удобного расширения.
4. БД. Мой совет тебе использовать PDO. Довольно удобно и проще совместить с ООП.